# Spring Boot: ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa

Hello please I'm trying to get data from table which has foreign Key I'm using this query:

```
@Query(nativeQuery=true, value="select idroom, roomnumber " +
             "FROM room JOIN hospital ON  hospital.idhospital = room.hospital.idhospital  WHERE idhospital = ?1")

     List<Room> findRoomsByHospital(@Param("idhospital")  Long hospital);
```

I had this issue

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "hospital"
  Hint: There is an entry for table "hospital", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
```

**Room Entity :**

```
@Entity(name = "room")
@Table( name = "room",
        uniqueConstraints = {
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "roomnumber")

        })
public class Room {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
private Long idroom;

private  String roomnumber;

@ManyToOne
        (fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "idhospital")
private Hospital hospital;
```

**Hospital Entity :**

```
@Entity(name = "hospital")
@Table( name = "hospital",
        uniqueConstraints = {
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "name"),
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "administrativeAddress"),
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "finessNumber"),
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "siretNumber")
        })
public class Hospital {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Long idhospital;

    @NotBlank
    private String name;
    @NotBlank
    private String administrativeAddress;

    private Integer finessNumber;

    private Integer siretNumber;

      @OneToMany
        (fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "hospital")
     // @JoinColumn(name = "id")
       private Set<User> users;


    @OneToMany
            (fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,  mappedBy = "hospital")
    private Set<Room> rooms;
```

**=============================================================
=============================================================**

I'm newbie can't really fix this syntax issue, please  help thnx.

Answer (score 1):

I added :  `@JsonIgnore` and it works

Solution to this problem is :

```
@ManyToOne
            (fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "idhospital")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Hospital hospital;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using nativeQuery=true, hence that room.hospital.idhospital not gonna work.
A simple solution for you is using query method. You don't need the @Query at all. **_IdHospital** depends on this field's naming in the Hospital entity (maybe post the Hospital entity and I can give you a correct answer):

```
List<Room> findByHospital_IdHospital(Long idhospital)
```

Comment: I tried this solution but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Please post your Entity classes.

Comment: I added it to the post can u check it please.

Comment: Please add the Hospital class as well, and the Repository class you're using

Comment: I added the Hospital class but the repo nothing is working is exactly the problem.

Comment: I tried this one now but same thing Error:                                                                                List<Room> findAllByHospital_Idhospital(Long hospital);